# TDOA based localization of dynamic object

Tags: tracking, localization

Does TDOA based localization give estimated local coordinates with both positive and negative range error.

Let me explain

When i obtain localized coordinates using TDOA of moving object, sometimes the estimated coordinates lies in front of the actual position (positive range error) and sometimes it falls behind the actual position of object (negative range error).

Now what i want to ask is that is this normal for the TDOA based localization coordinates or i am making mistake in my algorithm implementation ?

Comment: It is normal. Why do you think that it is not?

Comment: The picture I had in mind was that I was assure that TDOA would have error in azimuth and I was confused with any range error associated with the TDOA measurements. 

can u tell me reasons for it.

Comment: Sorry I really don't understand your question.